HP ProLiant 380G8 HDD tray staus blinks
I upgraded my RAID6 with two additional drives. Now have six 8TB drives in it. After adding, I modified arraysize to max (SSACLI installed on PVE), restarted and tuned the partition (parted, ext4).
This all took some hours, but in the end controller says OK, drives say OK, parted says OK - all OK.

root@asgard:~# ssacli ctrl slot=3 show config

Smart Array P420 in Slot 3                (sn: PDSXK0BRH7D1C9)

   Gen8 ServBP 12+2 at Port 2I, Box 1, OK


   Port Name: 1I

   Port Name: 2I

[...]

   Array E (SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)

      logicaldrive 7 (29.11 TB, RAID 6, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:9 (port 2I:box 1:bay 9, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)


root@asgard:~# ssacli ctrl slot=3 ld 7 show detail

Smart Array P420 in Slot 3

   Array E

      Logical Drive: 7
         Size: 29.11 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 6
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 1024 KB
         Status: OK
         Unrecoverable Media Errors: None
         Caching:  Disabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C86D80F77048AACBFB61F
         Disk Name: /dev/sde 
         Mount Points: None
         Logical Drive Label: AFA0EEE1PDSXK0BRH7D1C98B94
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: All disabled

But one drives-tray-status-icon is blinking green. Its not drive-tray of an added drive.
The documentation says "The drive is rebuilding or performing a RAID migration, stripe size migration, capacity expansion, or logical drive extension, or is erasing." But there is no such job in progress, no information about a running job anywhere.
Does anyone know about 1of6 array-drives is blinking green?

Try to reset the LED state using commands similar to this (or, you can specify your suspected drive instead of "all"):
ssacli controller slot=3 physicaldrive all modify led=on
ssacli controller slot=3 physicaldrive all modify led=off

this is normally a command to blink drive's LED to "locate" a drive:
<target> modify [led=on|off][duration=1-86400]
   Flashes specified device's LEDs. An optional duration parameter may be
   specified. Range is from 1 to 86400 seconds. Default is 3600.
   The target can be any valid individual device target. The "all", "alldata", 
   "allspares", or "allunassigned" targets can also be used.

   controller slot=1 array B modify led=on
   controller slot=1 array B modify led=on duration=600
   ctrl slot=1 ld 1 modify led=on
   ctrl slot=1 ld all modify led=on
   ctrl slot=1 pd all modify led=on
   ctrl slot=1 pd alldata modify led=on
   ctrl slot=1 pd allspares modify led=on
   ctrl slot=1 pd allunassigned modify led=on


In your case, it seems it stuck in the wrong state, hopefully this will reset it. The commands are safe to execute, as they don't actually do anything except controlling LEDs.
If nothing helps, I'm afraid the power cycle will restore it into a sane state. And if it doesn't, ask HP support, what else you can do?

I had tried modify led=off for that specific drive, what failed. But turning on and off did work! Thanks!
